# Hide a field in list when new item created but show it when edit?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, 2013

Is it possible to hide a field in list when new item is created, but show it when the item is edited?

I figured out how to hide a field, but it will hide the field in the form no matter it is New/Edit.

thanks

Comment: Your using content type in content type?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [SPField.ShowInNewForm](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfield.showinnewform.aspx)  and [SPField.ShowInEditForm](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfield.showineditform%28v=office.15%29.aspx) properties to control the visibility of fields in form pages.

PowerShell example

```
$web = Get-SPWeb http://intranet.contoso.com
$list = $web.Lists["Tasks"]
$field = $list.Fields["TaskStatus"]
$field.ShowInNewForm = $False
$field.ShowInEditForm = $True
$field.Update()
$list.Update()
```

### CSOM (JavaScript) example

```
 function setFieldVisibility(listTitle,fieldTitle,showInNewForm,showInEditForm,showInDisplayForm, Success,Error) {
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var web = clientContext.get_web();
    var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle(listTitle);
    var field = list.get_fields().getByTitle(fieldTitle);

    field.setShowInNewForm(showInNewForm);
    field.setShowInEditForm(showInEditForm);
    field.setShowInDisplayForm(showInDisplayForm);

    field.update();
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(function() { 
         Success();
       },
       Error
    );
  }


setFieldVisibility('Tasks','Start Date',false,false,true, function(){
       console.log('Field visibility properties have been updated');
    },
    function(sender, args) {
       console.log('Error:' + args.get_message());
    }
);
```

Comment: You were faster :)

Comment: Oh, sorry about that ;)

Comment: thanks. is there a way to do this from site content (web UI)?

Comment: There is no way to update those properties via UI as far as i know, but you could perform it using JavaScript if you will (see an updated answer)

Answer (score 6):

I have lost few hours trying to do this with CSOM but I figure it out so if you want to use CSOM approach Sane.Amit answer will trow an error "Additional information: The node to be inserted is from a different document context."

The reason is in this line `fld.Update();`

If you use `SetShowInEditForm()`, `SetShowInNewForm()` or `SetShowInDisplayForm()` the field XML definition gets updated by these methods so calling field `Update()` trows an error because you are trying to update same XML twice for the same field instance, also you will get the same error if you use `SetShowInEditForm()` and `SetShowInNewForm()` and then you `ExecuteQuery()`.

So the correct way to update some field is:

```
Field fld = fldColl.GetByTitle('name of the field');
fld.SetShowInEditForm(false);
cc.ExecuteQuery();

fld.SetShowInNewForm(false);
cc.ExecuteQuery();

fld.SetShowInDisplayForm(false);
cc.ExecuteQuery();

fld.Title = "Some New Title";
fld.Description = "Some New Description";
fld.Update();
cc.ExecuteQuery();
```

Comment: Oh boy, this is something. Can I buy you a coffee for this finding, it literally saved the day.

Comment: In Client Side Object Model libraries version 16.1.3912.1204 this issue is fixed, so you don't need to do ExecuteQuery() after every SetShowIn...

Answer (score 4):

You may do something like this too.

```
ClientContext cc = new ClientContext(siteURL);
List li = cc.Web.Lists.GetByTitle('XYZ');
FieldCollection fldColl = li.Fields;
cc.Load(fldColl);
cc.ExecuteQuery();

Field fld = fldColl.GetByTitle('name of the field');
fld.SetShowInEditForm(false); //SetShowInNewForm(false) for new form
fld.Update();
cc.ExecuteQuery();
```

Comment: +1 for the CSOM approach :)